# Why is this line of Objective-C leaking memory?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, memory-management

I'm writing an iPhone app.  I have a header file that looks like this:

```
@interface EditTagsViewController : UITableViewController {
  NSMutableArray *allTags;
  NSMutableArray *selectedTags;
  NSInteger currentFavorite;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *allTags;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *selectedTags;
@property (nonatomic) NSInteger currentFavorite;
@end
```

In the implementation file, my viewDidLoad method looks like this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
  NSMutableArray *aTags = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[Tag findAllTags]];
  self.allTags = aTags;
  [aTags release];

  NSMutableArray *sTags = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[Tag findByFavoriteId:currentFavorite]];
  self.selectedTags = sTags;
  [sTags release];

  UIBarButtonItem *add = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd target:self action:@selector(addNewTag:)];
  self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = add;
  [add release];
  [super viewDidLoad];
}
```

Here is my dealloc method:

```
- (void)dealloc {
  [allTags release];
  [selectedTags release];
  [super dealloc];
}
```

What's confusing to me is that when I run the app both in the simulator and on the device itself, using Instruments (memory leaks), it tells me that this line in my viewDidLoad method is leaking an array:

```
self.selectedTags = sTags;
```

It's confusing because I'm using the exact same technique with 2 different variables, and yet no leak is reported with the first one.

I feel like I'm missing something obvious here.  Any ideas?

Comment: What specifically is Instruments telling you? It generally can only tell you that an object *allocated* at a particular line has leaked, but not that that line is the cause of the leak. If something else in your code over-retains or under-releases the array, then it can leak but the code you've shown wouldn't be responsible. Also, you really should not make a property have a mutable type. That allows for violations of encapsulation, where outside code can change the state of the object behind its back.

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks correct to me.  Is it possible that one of `[Tag findAllTags]` or `[Tag findByFavoriteId:]` is leaking?  Are you making sure to set `self.allTags` and `self.selectedTags` to `nil` in `dealloc`?

Be mindful of the difference between saying `self.allTags = ...` and `allTags = ...`.  Because `allTags` is a property and has the `retain` attribute, whenever you assign via `self.allTags = ...`, it implicitly calls the setter method `[self setAllTags:...]`, which invokes `retain` on the new value and `release` on the old value (if any).  You're doing it correctly in this code sample, but if elsewhere you're assigning straight to `allTags` (without the `self.`), you're not `release`ing the old value, which may be the source of the leak.  Likewise for `selectedTags`.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at `findByFavoriteId` is there a `retain` there? That is the only difference I can see between the `aTags` and `sTags` are used in your example